# Updating webpage element with Java Spring MVC + Thymeleaf without refreshing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, page-refresh

I am building a webapp that monitors the status of a series of sensor nodes & actuators by means of the COAP protocol. When I get a new reading (such as a variation in temperature) I would like to update the corresponding data on the webpage.

On the webpage I have a table containing info of all nodes, one node per row.
Ideally, I would like to "fetch" the table row of the corresponding node and change the temperature value with the new one.

I can't find a way to do this inside a Spring controller.

This is the HTML Thymeleaf table:

```html
<table style="display: inline-block" id="actuatorTable" border="1px solid black">
    <thead style="font-weight:bold;">
    <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>IP</th>
        <th>TYPE</th>
        <th>RESOURCE</th>
        <th>VALUE</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="actuator: ${actuators}">
        <td th:utext="${actuator.nodeName}"></td>
        <td th:utext="${actuator.nodeIP}"></td>
        <td th:utext="${actuator.nodeType}"></td>
        <td th:utext="${actuator.nodeResource}"></td>
        <td th:utext="${actuator.currentValue}"></td>
        <td><button th:nodeIP="${actuator.nodeIP}" onclick="changeStatus(this.getAttribute('nodeIP'), 'on')">ON</button></td>
        <td><button th:nodeIP="${actuator.nodeIP}" onclick="changeStatus(this.getAttribute('nodeIP'), 'off')">OFF</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That is not really possible. Thymeleaf just renders the view and hands it over to the browser. You will need to either implement some kind of auto-refresh of the page in the browser (using JavaScript). Or you can set up a websocket between the browser and the server to push the changes and use JavaScript to manipulate the DOM to show the changes.